# Geometrics: Symetric scoring calculate

Tags: geometry, symmetry

After reading some of "The Symmetries of Things", I've tried to look if Im understanding the concept correctly...
I'm trying to calculate the next picture symetric:
[image]

Each triangle gives us $$`*`$$ since its kleidoscopes.
Also we have wanderings, so I get also $$`o`$$

A total score of $$*o$$ which is equal to $$ 3$  $$
According to the magic thorem...which means I have a mistake(since it cant get more then 2$ of symmetrics...)

Please help me to find where am I wrong?

references:
https://www.crcpress.com/The-Symmetries-of-Things/Conway-Burgiel-Goodman-Strauss/p/book/9781568812205#googlePreviewContainer
(You can read all what im asking on the preview section).

http://blog.kleinproject.org/?p=1381

Edit:

Another option i found(not sure about it),
maybe its not wanderings instead its a miracle which gives us the score $$x$$
A total of $$*x$$ score which is then $$ 2$ $$ and could be correct according to the magic thorem.

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Have you seen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group) and
(https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group_diagrams) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found,
Since it has 45,45,90 degrees and reflection,
score is *442 (reflection+pi/4+pi/4+pi/2)
which is equal to 1$+3/8$+3/8$+1/4$=2$ 
Correct by the magic thorem.
thanks everyone!